# How to create a Sine Waves using Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, waveform, trigonometry

I am able to create a Wave Form using Core Plot in my iPhone app but its not like Sine Wave. 
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9qztmaq6mzmhkn/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-05%20at%2011.28.20%20AM.png) is the link on which you can see how the waves are generated but I want to show these waves in Sine Wave form. Which Algorithm I should have to follow? Please suggest!

(Since I have only 1 reputation so I can't add the photo so shared a link)

Comment: @Monolo Thanks for the suggestion! I would like to inform you that I need to create the Sine Wave when user will record the song and listen the song. In that case the value of y axis (amplitude) will be dynamic. I have used Core Plot for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the right x and y coordinates. And think, that should give you the sine-wave.

If we try to implement simple sine formula -

y(t) = A*sin(w*t + phase)

> ```
> float y; for(float x=rect.origin.x; x < rect.size.width; x++) {
> y = ((rect.size.height/4) * sin(0.3 * x + 0));
> NSLog(@"x = %f \t y = %f \n",x,y); }
> ```

try to use these values, and let me know, how it comes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will let you know how it will come but can you please explain me how it will draw the waves for -y?

Comment: What are you asking about? About getting negative Y values or about plotting it?

Comment: After some modification it worked for me! Thanks! Accepted your answer